# Need help aligning conky objects

Tags: 12.04, conky

I've been using Conky a long time, and one thing I just can't seem to get looking nice is the network graph.

The graphs start on the right hand side, and scroll to the left. I want the starting point for the graphs to match up. You can see that the Down graph starts a little more to the right than the Up graph. They are the same legnth they just don't line up. Can anyone help me accomplish this? I've tried a few ways like making "Down" and "Up" alignL, then having the graphs alignC, then the kb info alignR but that didn't work.

Here's my current network config, paired with a screenshot:

> ${font Arial:bold:size=10}${color #342826}NETWORK ${color #747170}${hr
>   2} $font${color #E8E8E8}IP on eth1 ${alignr} ${addr eth1}
>
> Down ${downspeedgraph eth1 12,120 000000} $alignr ${downspeed eth1} Up
>   ${upspeedgraph eth1 12,120 000000} $alignr ${upspeed eth1}
>
> Downloaded: $alignr ${totaldown eth1} Uploaded: $alignr ${totalup
>   eth1}

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the width of your conky is 250.

Adapt your code:

`Down ${downspeedgraph eth1 12,120 000000} $alignr ${downspeed eth1} Up ${upspeedgraph eth1 12,120 000000} $alignr ${upspeed eth1}`

to:

`Down${goto 45}${downspeedgraph eth1 12,150 000000}${alignr}${downspeed eth1}`
`Up${goto 45}${upspeedgraph eth1 12,150 000000}${alignr}${upspeed eth1}`

The goto command orders the following argument to a specific distance counted in pixels from the left side of the conky window.

You may have to alter the numerical values in my code to adapt them to your conky.